# Compare id of two array, then set value equa to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have two array like this:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {id: "1", icon: Images.icon.food, checkable: false, text: 'Dine-in', description: "coupon for dine in"},
  {id: "2", icon: Images.icon.delivery, checkable: false, text: 'Delivery', description: "coupon for delivery"},
  {id: "3", icon: Images.icon.collection, checkable: false, text: 'Collection', description: "coupon for collection"},
]

let arr2 = [
  {description: "Dine in Service", id: "13", isActive: false, name: "Dine In", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "1", slug: "dine-in"},
  {description: "Delivery Service", id: "14", isActive: true, name: "Delivery", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "2", slug:"delivery"},
  {description: "Collection Service", id: "15", isActive: true, name: "Collection", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "3", slug: "collection"}
]
```

How to compare `id` of `arr1` equa to `serviceId` of `arr2`, and then set value `checkable` in `arr1` equa to `isActice` in `arr2`

This is result I want to be:

```js
result = [
    {id: "1", icon: Images.icon.food, checkable: false, text: 'Dine-in', description: "coupon for dine in"},
    {id: "2", icon: Images.icon.delivery, checkable: true, text: 'Delivery', description: "coupon for delivery"},
    {id: "3", icon: Images.icon.collection, checkable: true, text: 'Collection', description: "coupon for collection"},
]
```

Means `result` like `arr1` but change `checkable` equa to `isActive` of `arr2`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can simply use find and use an arrow function to define the comparision expression. And then you can simply do the attribution directly

```js
let arr1 = [
  {id: "1", icon: 'food', checkable: false, text: 'Dine-in', description: "coupon for dine in"},
  {id: "2", icon: 'delivery', checkable: false, text: 'Delivery', description: "coupon for delivery"},
  {id: "3", icon: 'collection', checkable: false, text: 'Collection', description: "coupon for collection"},
];

let arr2 = [
  {description: "Dine in Service", id: "13", isActive: false, name: "Dine In", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "1", slug: "dine-in"},
  {description: "Delivery Service", id: "14", isActive: true, name: "Delivery", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "2", slug:"delivery"},
  {description: "Collection Service", id: "15", isActive: true, name: "Collection", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "3", slug: "collection"}
];



for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    arr1[i].checkable = arr2.find(x => x.serviceId == arr1[i].id).isActive;
    console.log(arr1[i]);
}
```

If you prefer a one line forEach

```
arr1.forEach((array1) => array1.checkable = arr2.find(x => x.serviceId == array1.id).isActive );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all active states in an object and map new object with the state.

```js
let arr1 = [{ id: "1", icon: 'Images.icon.food', checkable: false, text: 'Dine-in', description: "coupon for dine in" }, { id: "2", icon: 'Images.icon.delivery', checkable: false, text: 'Delivery', description: "coupon for delivery" }, { id: "3", icon: 'Images.icon.collection', checkable: false, text: 'Collection', description: "coupon for collection" }],
    arr2 = [{ description: "Dine in Service", id: "13", isActive: false, name: "Dine In", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "1", slug: "dine-in" }, { description: "Delivery Service", id: "14", isActive: true, name: "Delivery", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "2", slug:"delivery" }, { description: "Collection Service", id: "15", isActive: true, name: "Collection", serviceDetail: null, serviceId: "3", slug: "collection" }],
    isActive = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(({ serviceId, isActive }) => [serviceId, isActive])),
    result = arr1.map(o => ({ ...o, isActive: isActive[o.id] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```